# Variable Input Mask

Tags: ms-access

I have a report with a few calculations on it that gives weights in kg. The weights vary from 12.5kg to 1200kg. This is driving me crazy but I can't figure out how to make an input mask for this field! If the weight has a decimal place it won't put the "kg" behind it.

Comment: Why would you use an input mask? Add an appropriate label to the field ("Weight (kg)")

Comment: That is what I have now, I guess it will have to do. I'm being too picky! haha

Comment: If you want kg appended to the value, can use an expression in textbox ControlSource that concatenates. However, don't think I would do that. I use a label behind the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the table set the required field as follows: `Field size: Double, Format: Standard, Decimal places: 2.` This will let you save decimal values.

At the report set 'Format' property  to `&" Kg"` for required control. I have attached a few screenshots :

[image: Table properties],

[image: Report properties],

[image: Result]

Hope this helps .

Comment: this seems more a comment that a proper answer.

Comment: I have amended my post and included few screenshots. Hope this provides answer now.